# Why does X[Y] join of data.tables not allow a full outer join, or a left join?

Tags: r, join, data.table

This is a bit of a philosophical question about data.table join syntax. I am finding more and more uses for data.tables, but still learning...

The join format `X[Y]` for data.tables is very concise, handy and efficient, but as far as I can tell, it only supports inner joins and right outer joins. To get a left or full outer join, I need to use `merge`:

- `X[Y, nomatch = NA]` -- all rows in Y -- right outer join  (default)
- `X[Y, nomatch = 0]` -- only rows with matches in both X and Y -- inner join
- `merge(X, Y, all = TRUE)` -- all rows from both X and Y -- full outer join
- `merge(X, Y, all.x = TRUE)` -- all rows in X -- left outer join

It seems to me that it would be handy if the `X[Y]` join format supported all 4 types of joins. Is there a reason only two types of joins are supported?

For me, the `nomatch = 0` and `nomatch = NA` parameter values are not very intuitive for the actions being performed. It is easier for me to understand and remember the `merge` syntax: `all = TRUE`, `all.x = TRUE` and `all.y = TRUE`. Since the `X[Y]` operation resembles `merge` much more than `match`, why not use the `merge` syntax for joins rather than the `match` function's `nomatch` parameter?

Here are code examples of the 4 join types:

```
# sample X and Y data.tables
library(data.table)
X <- data.table(t = 1:4, a = (1:4)^2)
setkey(X, t)
X
#    t  a
# 1: 1  1
# 2: 2  4
# 3: 3  9
# 4: 4 16

Y <- data.table(t = 3:6, b = (3:6)^2)
setkey(Y, t)
Y
#    t  b
# 1: 3  9
# 2: 4 16
# 3: 5 25
# 4: 6 36

# all rows from Y - right outer join
X[Y]  # default
#  t  a  b
# 1: 3  9  9
# 2: 4 16 16
# 3: 5 NA 25
# 4: 6 NA 36

X[Y, nomatch = NA]  # same as above
#    t  a  b
# 1: 3  9  9
# 2: 4 16 16
# 3: 5 NA 25
# 4: 6 NA 36

merge(X, Y, by = "t", all.y = TRUE)  # same as above
#    t  a  b
# 1: 3  9  9
# 2: 4 16 16
# 3: 5 NA 25
# 4: 6 NA 36

identical(X[Y], merge(X, Y, by = "t", all.y = TRUE))
# [1] TRUE

# only rows in both X and Y - inner join
X[Y, nomatch = 0]  
#    t  a  b
# 1: 3  9  9
# 2: 4 16 16

merge(X, Y, by = "t")  # same as above
#    t  a  b
# 1: 3  9  9
# 2: 4 16 16

merge(X, Y, by = "t", all = FALSE)  # same as above
#    t  a  b
# 1: 3  9  9
# 2: 4 16 16

identical( X[Y, nomatch = 0], merge(X, Y, by = "t", all = FALSE) )
# [1] TRUE

# all rows from X - left outer join
merge(X, Y, by = "t", all.x = TRUE)
#    t  a  b
# 1: 1  1 NA
# 2: 2  4 NA
# 3: 3  9  9
# 4: 4 16 16

# all rows from both X and Y - full outer join
merge(X, Y, by = "t", all = TRUE)
#    t  a  b
# 1: 1  1 NA
# 2: 2  4 NA
# 3: 3  9  9
# 4: 4 16 16
# 5: 5 NA 25
# 6: 6 NA 36
```

Update: data.table v1.9.6 introduced the `on=` syntax, which allows ad hoc joins on fields other than the primary key. [jangorecki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34219998/1694807) to the question [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/1694807) provides some examples of additional join types that data.table can handle.

Comment: Have you read [FAQ 1.12](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf)? You can always call `Y[X]` if you want the *left outer join* of `X[Y]` and `rbind(Y[X],X[Y])` if you want a full outer join

Comment: See my answer for a more data.table approach to the full outer join

Comment: @mnel, I assume your `unique()` approach below for the full join is preferable to `rbind(Y[X],X[Y])`, since the rbind would involve copying the table. Is that right?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, yes. I haven't tested whether three smaller unique calls are quicker than one large (eg `unique(c(unique(X[,t]), unique(Y[,t]))` -- this should be more memory efficient as it is only combining two lists that are going to be less than or equal to the number of rows in X and Y.

Comment: Your question such a good description; I found answers to my questions in your question. Thanks

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To quote from the `data.table` [FAQ 1.11 What is the difference between `X[Y]` and `merge(X, Y)`?](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#MergeDiff)

> `X[Y]` is a join, looking up X's rows using Y (or Y's key if it has one) as an index.
>
> `Y[X]` is a join, looking up Y's rows using X (or X's key if it has one)
>
> `merge(X,Y)` does both ways at the same time. The number of rows of `X[Y]` and `Y[X]` usually differ, whereas the number of rows returned by `merge(X,Y)` and `merge(Y,X)` is the same.
>
> BUT that misses the main point. Most tasks require something to be done on the
>   data after a join or merge. Why merge all the columns of data, only to
>   use a small subset of them afterwards? You may suggest
>   `merge(X[,ColsNeeded1],Y[,ColsNeeded2])`, but that requires the programmer to work out which columns are needed. `X[Y,j`] in data.table does all that in one step for
>   you. When you write `X[Y,sum(foo*bar)]`, data.table automatically inspects the `j` expression to see which columns it uses. It will only subset those columns only; the others are ignored. Memory is only created for the columns the `j` uses, and `Y` columns enjoy standard R recycling rules within the context of each group. Let's say `foo` is in `X`, and bar is in `Y` (along with 20 other columns in `Y`). Isn't `X[Y,sum(foo*bar)]` quicker to program and quicker to run than a merge of everything wastefully followed by a subset?

---

If you want a left outer join of `X[Y]`

```
le <- Y[X]
mallx <- merge(X, Y, all.x = T)
# the column order is different so change to be the same as `merge`
setcolorder(le, names(mallx))
identical(le, mallx)
# [1] TRUE
```

If you want a full outer join

```
# the unique values for the keys over both data sets
unique_keys <- unique(c(X[,t], Y[,t]))
Y[X[J(unique_keys)]]
##   t  b  a
## 1: 1 NA  1
## 2: 2 NA  4
## 3: 3  9  9
## 4: 4 16 16
## 5: 5 25 NA
## 6: 6 36 NA

# The following will give the same with the column order X,Y
X[Y[J(unique_keys)]]
```

Comment: Thanks @mnel. FAQ 1.12 doesn't mention full or left outer join. Your full outer join suggestion with unique() is a great help. That ought to be in the FAQ. I know Matthew Dowle "designed it for his own use, and he wanted it that way." (FAQ 1.9), but I thought  `X[Y,all=T]` could be an elegant way to specify a full outer join within the data.table X[Y] syntax. Or `X[Y,all.x=T]` for the left join. I wondered why it wasn't designed that way. Just a thought.

Comment: @DouglasClark Have added answer, and filed [2302:Add mnel's merge join syntax to FAQ (with timings)](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2302&group_id=240&atid=978). Great suggestions!

Comment: @mnel Is there any way we can impute NA's with 0 when performing `X[Y[J(unique_keys)]]` ?

Comment: @mnel also worth to note LEFT OUTER JOIN usage while chaining can be the following: `X[...][Y[.SD]][...]`

Comment: The J is basically the same as calling a list so that the result is a data table. It could be replaced by .() or list(), but the J is used to improve readability for joins. More details here: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/J

Comment: @mnel unique_keys <- union(X[,t], Y[,t]) would do the job with lesser keystrokes

Comment: what impresses me about data.table documentation is that it can be so verbose, yet remain so cryptic...

Comment: Is there any way to extend ```X[Y[J(unique_keys)]]``` approach to full outer join with multiple keys?

Answer (score 29):

@mnel's answer is spot on, so do accept that answer. This is just follow up, too long for comments.

As mnel says, left/right outer join is obtained by swapping `Y` and `X`: `Y[X]` -vs- `X[Y]`. So 3 of the 4 join types are supported in that syntax, not 2, iiuc.

Adding the 4th seems a good idea. Let's say we add `full=TRUE` or `both=TRUE` or `merge=TRUE` (not sure the best argument name?) then it hadn't occurred to me before that `X[Y,j,merge=TRUE]` would be useful for the reasons after the BUT in FAQ 1.12. New feature request now added and linked back here, thanks :

[FR#2301 : Add merge=TRUE argument for both X[Y] and Y[X] join like merge() does.](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/614)

Recent versions have sped up `merge.data.table` (by taking a shallow copy internally to set the keys more efficiently, for example). So we are trying to bring `merge()` and `X[Y]` closer, and provide all options to user for full flexibility. There are pros and cons of both. Another outstanding feature request is :

[FR#2033 : Add by.x and by.y to merge.data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/637)

If there are any others, please keep them coming.

By this part in the question :

> why not use the merge syntax for joins rather than the match function's nomatch parameter?

If you prefer `merge()` syntax and its 3 arguments `all`,`all.x` and `all.y` then just use that instead of `X[Y]`. Think it should cover all the cases. Or did you mean why is the argument a single `nomatch` in `[.data.table`?  If so, it's just the way that seemed natural given FAQ 2.14 : "Can you explain further why data.table is inspired by A[B] syntax in base?". But also, `nomatch` only takes two values currently `0` and `NA`. That could be extended so that a negative value meant something, or 12 would mean use the 12th row's values to fill in NAs, for example, or `nomatch` in future could be a vector or even itself a `data.table`.

Hm. How would *by-without-by* interact with merge=TRUE? Perhaps we should take this over to [datatable-help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/datatable-help-f2315188.html).

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. @mnel's answer is excellent, but my question was not how to do a full or left join, but "Is there a reason only two types of joins are supported?" So now it's a bit more philosophical ;-)  Actually I don't prefer merge syntax, but there appears to an R tradition for building on existing stuff folks are familiar with. I had scribbled `join="all", join="all.x", join="all.y" and join="x.and.y"` in the margin of my notes. Not sure if that is any better.

Comment: @DouglasClark Maybe `join` like that, good idea. I posted to datatable-help so let's see. Maybe give `data.table` some time to settle in, too. Have you got to _by-without-by_ yet for example, and _join inherited scope_?

Comment: As indicated in my comment above, I suggest adding a `join` keyword to , when i is a datatable: `X[Y,j,join=string]`. The possible string values for join are suggested to be: 1) "all.y" and "right" -

Comment: @DouglasClark Sounds good to me. Please file a feature request [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240) so it doesn't get forgotten.

Comment: Hi Matt, the data.table library is fantastic; thank you for that; though I think the join behavior (being a right outer join by default) should be explained prominently in the main documentation; it took me 3 days to figure this out.

Comment: @tucson Thanks for the feedback. Good idea, will do. Even better if you could suggest exactly where in the documentation and exactly what to write. Would adding a link to FAQ 2.14 to the `?data.table` page suffice?

Comment: I propose to update datatable-intro.pdf with a chapter [4. Join], and a Table of Content in the same doc.
[4. Join] could explain that "data.table join is done as follows: [example]. DATA.TABLE JOIN IS A RIGHT OUTER JOIN BY DEFAULT.
[4.1 Right outer join (default option)]
[4.2 Left outer join]
[4.3 Inner join]
[4.4 Full outer join]
Each paragraph giving a simple example.

Comment: @tucson I see, good idea. Ok will add to list to do that. Thanks.

Comment: @tucson Just to link here, now filed as [issue #709](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/709).

Answer (score 20):

This "answer" is a proposal for discussion: As indicated in my comment, I suggest adding a `join` parameter to [.data.table() to enable additional types of joins, ie: `X[Y,j,join=string]`. In addition to the 4 types of ordinary joins, I also suggest to support 3 types of *exclusive* joins, and the *cross* join.

The `join` string values (and aliases) for the various join types are proposed to be:

1. `"all.y"` and `"right"` -- right join, the present data.table default (nomatch=NA) - 
                             all Y rows with NAs where there is no X match;
2. `"both"` and `"inner"`  -- inner join (nomatch=0) - only rows where X and Y match;
3. `"all.x"` and `"left"`  -- left join - all rows from X, NAs where no Y match:
4. `"outer"` and `"full"`  -- full outer join - all rows from X and Y, NAs where no match
5. `"only.x"` and `"not.y"` -- non-join or anti-join returning X rows where there is no Y match
6. `"only.y"`  and `"not.x"` -- non-join or anti-join returning Y rows where there is no X match
7. `"not.both"` -- exclusive join returning X and Y rows where there is no match to the other table, ie an exclusive-or (XOR)
8. `"cross"` -- cross join or *Cartesian product* with each row of X matched to each row of Y

The default value is `join="all.y"` which corresponds to the present default.

The "all", "all.x" and "all.y" string values correspond to `merge()` parameters. The "right", "left", "inner" and "outer" strings may be more amenable to SQL users.

The "both" and "not.both" strings are my best suggestion at the moment -- but someone may have better string suggestions for the inner join and exclusive join. (I'm not sure if "exclusive" is the right terminology, correct me if there is a proper term for an "XOR" join.)

Use of `join="not.y"` is an alternative for  `X[-Y,j]` or `X[!Y,j]` non-join syntax and maybe more clear (to me), although I'm not sure if they are the same (new feature in data.table version 1.8.3).

The cross join can be handy sometimes, but it may not fit in the data.table paradigm.

Comment: Please send this to [datatable-help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/datatable-help-f2315188.html) for discussion.

Comment: +1 But, _please_ either send to [datatable-help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/datatable-help-f2315188.html), or file a [feature request](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240). I don't mind adding `join` but unless it gets onto the tracker, it'll get forgotten.

Comment: I see you haven't logged in to S.O. for a while. So I've filed this in [FR#2301](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2301&group_id=240&atid=978)

Comment: @MattDowle, +1 for this feature. (Tried doing it via [FR#2301](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2301&group_id=240&atid=978) but I get a permissions denied message).

Comment: @adilapapaya  We moved from RForge to GitHub.  Please +1 here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/614. Arun ported the issues over so they weren't lost.

Comment: Perhaps this is already possible but I haven't found how. Any chance data.table package could allow where to add columns when doing a join. Atm the right outer join X[Y] generally does what I want but it puts all the columns in X at the beginning of the data.table while I generally want them at the end. Also, is it possible to assign values to `NA` when doing a join? I generally have to do this afterward and find this rather cumbersome... Thanks