# Merging two sets of data by data.table roll='nearest' function

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have two sets of data.

Sample of `set_A` (total number of rows: 45467):

```
ID_a    a1  a2  a3  time_a
2   35694   5245.2  301.6053    00.00944
3   85694   9278.9  301.6051    23.00972
4   65694   9375.2  301.6049    22.00972
5   85653   4375.5  301.6047    19.00972
6   12694   5236.3  301.6045    22.00972
7   85697   5345.2  301.6043    21.00972
8   85640   5274.1  301.6041    20.01000
9   30694   5279.0  301.6039    20.01000
```

Sample of `set_B` (total number of rows: 4798):

```
ID_b    b1  b2  source  time_b
2   34.20   15.114  set1.csv.1  20.35750
7   67.20   16.114  set1.csv.2  21.35778
12  12.20   33.114  set1.csv.3  22.35806
17  73.20   67.114  set2.csv.1  23.35833
23  88.20   42.114  set2.csv.2  19.35861
28  90.20   52.114  set3.csv.1  00.35889
```

I am interested in a result where to the `set_B`, rows from `set_A` are matched by the nearest values of `time_a` and `time_b` (total number of output rows: 4798). In `set_A` values of `time_a` could be repeated several times (eg. `ID_a[8,]` and `[ID_a[9,]`) - it doesn't really matter which row will be merged with a row from `set_B` (in this case `ID_b[1,]`). Example of the expected result:

```
ID_b    b1  b2  source  time_b      ID_a    a1  a2  a3  time_a
2   34.20   15.114  set1.csv.1  20.35750    8   85640   5274.1  301.6041    20.01000
7   67.20   16.114  set1.csv.2  21.35778    7   85697   5345.2  301.6043    21.00972
12  12.20   33.114  set1.csv.3  22.35806    4   65694   9375.2  301.6049    22.00972
17  73.20   67.114  set2.csv.1  23.35833    3   85694   9278.9  301.6051    23.00972
23  88.20   42.114  set2.csv.2  19.35861    5   85653   4375.5  301.6047    19.00972
28  90.20   52.114  set3.csv.1  00.35889    2   35694   5245.2  301.6053    00.00944
```

I went through many similar questions on stackoverflow and I really like `data.table` library codes as they look really elegant. However, I made several failed attempts where I received either a table constructed based on two sets (total no. of rows 45467) or merged only one column `time_a` to the `set_B`... Nevertheless, I won't be picky and if somebody has another idea I would be very grateful for help.

Example of a code on which I'm working on:

```
setDT(set_B)
setDT(set_A)
setkey(set_B, time_b) [, time_a:=time_b]
test_ab <- set_B[set_A, roll='nearest']
```

As a result I am receiving not only a table with data which should be neglaced but also "a mess" in column names (e.g. a column which contains `ID_a` values is called `time_a`).

I would really appricieate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step example based on the sample data you give:

```
# Sample data
library(data.table)
setDT(set_A)
setDT(set_B)    

# Create time column by which to do a rolling join
set_A[, time := time_a]
set_B[, time := time_b]
setkey(set_A, time)
setkey(set_B, time)

# Rolling join by nearest time
set_merged <- set_B[set_A, roll = "nearest"]

unique(set_merged[order(ID_b)], by = "time")
#    ID_b   b1     b2     source   time_b     time ID_a    a1     a2       a3
# 1:    2 34.2 15.114 set1.csv.1 20.35750 20.01000    8 85640 5274.1 301.6041
# 2:    7 67.2 16.114 set1.csv.2 21.35778 21.00972    7 85697 5345.2 301.6043
# 3:   12 12.2 33.114 set1.csv.3 22.35806 22.00972    4 65694 9375.2 301.6049
# 4:   17 73.2 67.114 set2.csv.1 23.35833 23.00972    3 85694 9278.9 301.6051
# 5:   23 88.2 42.114 set2.csv.2 19.35861 19.00972    5 85653 4375.5 301.6047
# 6:   28 90.2 52.114 set3.csv.1  0.35889  0.00944    2 35694 5245.2 301.6053
#      time_a
# 1: 20.01000
# 2: 21.00972
# 3: 22.00972
# 4: 23.00972
# 5: 19.00972
# 6:  0.00944
```

Two comments:

1. We create a new `time` column to avoid losing one of the original time columns from `set_A` and `set_B`. You can always remove the `time` column after the join if required.
2. We use `unique` to remove duplicated `time` rows by order of `ID_b`. You mention in your post that *"it doesn't really matter which row will be merged"* but in case that you do want to retain *specific* rows, you might need to adjust this line of code.

---

### Update (thanks to @Henrik)

As @Henrik pointed out, what you're after is actually a rolling join of `set_A` with respect to `set_B`, in which case you don't need to deal with the duplicate rows.

That translates to

```
library(data.table)
setDT(set_A)
setDT(set_B)    

# Create time column by which to do a rolling join
set_A[, time := time_a]
set_B[, time := time_b]

set_A[set_B, on = "time", roll = "nearest"][order(ID_a)]
#   ID_a    a1     a2       a3   time_a     time ID_b   b1     b2     source
#1:    2 35694 5245.2 301.6053  0.00944  0.35889   28 90.2 52.114 set3.csv.1
#2:    3 85694 9278.9 301.6051 23.00972 23.35833   17 73.2 67.114 set2.csv.1
#3:    5 85653 4375.5 301.6047 19.00972 19.35861   23 88.2 42.114 set2.csv.2
#4:    6 12694 5236.3 301.6045 22.00972 22.35806   12 12.2 33.114 set1.csv.3
#5:    7 85697 5345.2 301.6043 21.00972 21.35778    7 67.2 16.114 set1.csv.2
#6:    9 30694 5279.0 301.6039 20.01000 20.35750    2 34.2 15.114 set1.csv.1
#  time_b
#1:  0.35889
#2: 23.35833
#3: 19.35861
#4: 22.35806
#5: 21.35778
#6: 20.35750
```

---

### Sample data

```
set_A <- read.table(text =
    "ID_a    a1  a2  a3  time_a
2   35694   5245.2  301.6053    00.00944
3   85694   9278.9  301.6051    23.00972
4   65694   9375.2  301.6049    22.00972
5   85653   4375.5  301.6047    19.00972
6   12694   5236.3  301.6045    22.00972
7   85697   5345.2  301.6043    21.00972
8   85640   5274.1  301.6041    20.01000
9   30694   5279.0  301.6039    20.01000", header = T)

set_B <- read.table(text =
    "ID_b    b1  b2  source  time_b
2   34.20   15.114  set1.csv.1  20.35750
7   67.20   16.114  set1.csv.2  21.35778
12  12.20   33.114  set1.csv.3  22.35806
17  73.20   67.114  set2.csv.1  23.35833
23  88.20   42.114  set2.csv.2  19.35861
28  90.20   52.114  set3.csv.1  00.35889", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code and simple clear explanation, it helped a lot! I've just made one change in line: `unique(set_merged[order(ID_b)], by = "time")`
Instead, I've written 
`unique(set_merged[order(ID_b)], by = "ID_b")` as some values of time in `set_B` were duplicated as well (`ID_b` is unique).

Comment: Don't you want to use "set_B" in `i` to lookup rows of "set_A" in `x`? `set_A[set_B, on="time", roll = "nearest"]`. Then you don't need the `unique` step. Furthermore, if you use `on`, the two `setkey` steps are not needed. Also, `setDT` updates by reference, so the assignment (`<-`) is redundant. Note that due to the duplicated times in 'set_A', some matches differ.

Comment: small addition: if you use `fread` in stead of `read.table`, the result of the read is already a `data.table`. It also is (or seems to be) better practice to use `TRUE`  in stead if `T`.

Comment: @Henrik From the original post (and from what I understand) it seems OP wants `set_B[set_A, ...]`. Thanks for pointing out the update-by-reference bit though, I've made a change.

Comment: Hi again @Maurits Evers! `set_B[set_A, ...]` is an outer join **with respect to 'set_A'**, i.e. the result contains all rows of 'set_A' (hence the need for your additional step). However, because the expected answer in OP contains the rows from 'set_B', my interpretation was that OP needed `set_A[set_B, ...]`, i.e. we use 'set_B' to lookup rows of 'set_A'. Well, well, OP is happy, so I suppose everything is fine then ;) Cheers.

Comment: Ah I see @Henrik; thanks for the clarification. I'm not too familiar with the `data.table` syntax yet. I've made an edit.

Comment: I think the small examples in this question (yes, in the actual question) is very nice to get a better feeling for the `data.table` join types: [Why does XY join of data.tables not allow a full outer join, or a left join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773822/why-does-xy-join-of-data-tables-not-allow-a-full-outer-join-or-a-left-join?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Personally, I like to use the `on` argument, rather than setting keys. In `x[i, on = , ...]` it's explicit what you are joining on. Some nice examples with `on` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right/34219998#34219998). Cheers

Comment: Hi everyon, I have made a similar question to this one, where I would like to merge two DF by multiple columns (instead of one only) following the method of the nearest values.
I think it could be interesting for you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455623/merging-two-data-sets-by-multiple-columns-and-by-data-table-roll-nearest-funct