Merge approx. same timeseries, round time (minutes)
I have two timeseries from two different sensors. Because of internal timestamp settings they differ in a few minutes. I would like to combine them, ignoring the exact time:
#Timeseries 1
t = seq(as.POSIXct('2024-04-11 14:03:00'), length.out = 10, by = '10 mins')
x = c(1,3,4,2,3, 3,4, 10,6, 25)
y<- xts(x, t)

#Timeseries 2
t1 = seq(as.POSIXct('2024-04-11 14:06:00'), length.out = 10, by = '10 mins')
x1 = c(3,4, 10,6, 25, 2,3,4,2, 3)
y1 <- xts(x1, t1)

# Merge data frames
merged <- merge(y, y1, all = TRUE)


merged


the data.table package has robust functionality for fuzzy / nearest / rolling type join operations. Here's a good illustration that looks ~analogous to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013468/merging-two-sets-of-data-by-data-table-roll-nearest-function

Please show the expected output.  Is the result one column? two columns? What does "combine" mean?

I suspect your are looking for
rbind(y, y1) 

if your toy data really mimics your real data accurately. We notice that rbind.xts() exists.

Something like below should work:
library(xts)
#Timeseries 1
t = seq(as.POSIXct('2024-04-11 14:03:00'), length.out = 10, by = '10 mins')
x = c(1,3,4,2,3, 3,4, 10,6, 25)
y<- xts(x, t)

#Timeseries 2
t1 = seq(as.POSIXct('2024-04-11 14:06:00'), length.out = 10, by = '10 mins')
x1 = c(3,4, 10,6, 25, 2,3,4,2, 3)
y1 <- xts(x1, t1)


# Merge data frames
merge(y, y1, all = TRUE) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  dplyr::mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(y), y1, y)) |>
  subset(select = -y1) |>
  xts::as.xts()
#>                      y
#> 2024-04-11 14:03:00  1
#> 2024-04-11 14:06:00  3
#> 2024-04-11 14:13:00  3
#> 2024-04-11 14:16:00  4
#> 2024-04-11 14:23:00  4
#> 2024-04-11 14:26:00 10
[...]

Created on 2024-11-04 with reprex v2.1.1

1) aggregate.zoo If by "combine" the question means produce an xts object with unique times rounded to the minute such that all data points at a particular minute after the time is rounded are aggregated by mean then use the following (or replace mean with min, max, or some other function depending on what is wanted).  Note that xts objects automatically sort by time. ?aggregate.zoo for more information.
library(lubridate)
# can replace "min" with "5 min" to round to 5 minutes, say
to.min <- function(x) round_date(x, "min")

# one column result    
c(y, y1) |> aggregate(to.min, mean, na.rm = TRUE) |> as.xts()

# two column result
merged |> aggregate(to.min, mean, na.rm = TRUE) |> as.xts()

2) preserve duplicates If what is wanted is to preserve duplicates rather than aggregate them and simply round the times to the minute then:
to.min.xts <- function(x) xts(x, to.min(time(x)))

# one column
to.min.xts(c(y, y1))

# two column
to.min.xts(merged)

3) cbind Or if what is meant by combine is to pair up the y and y1 elements (which are assumed to be of equal length as in the question) using the time of the y element and rounding to the minute to give a 2 column result then
to.min.xts(cbind(y = y, y1 = coredata(y1)))

4) findInterval Another possibility is to associate to each y1 the index ix (1, 2, 3, ...) of that y with the largest time less than or equal to the time of y1.  Such indexes must exist to use this.  Swap y and y1 if need be.  See ?findInterval.
ix <- findInterval(time(y1), time(y))
to.min.xts(cbind(y = coredata(y)[ix], y1 = y1))

5) nn2 If combine means find the nearest time in y1 to the time in y then:
library(RANN)

ix <- nn2(time(y), time(y1), 1)$nn.idx
to.min.xts(cbind(y = y, y1 = coredata(y1)[ix]))

Note
The input from the question is:
library(xts)
#Timeseries 1
t = seq(as.POSIXct('2024-04-11 14:03:00'), length.out = 10, by = '10 mins')
x = c(1,3,4,2,3, 3,4, 10,6, 25)
y<- xts(x, t)

#Timeseries 2
t1 = seq(as.POSIXct('2024-04-11 14:06:00'), length.out = 10, by = '10 mins')
x1 = c(3,4, 10,6, 25, 2,3,4,2, 3)
y1 <- xts(x1, t1)

merged <- merge(y, y1, all = TRUE)

