# Merging two data.tables using two columns in R

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following data.tables:

```
dt1 <- data.table(id_1 = 1:4,
                  name_1 = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), 
                  score_1 = 11:14)
# dt1:
   id_1 name_1 score_1
1:    1      a      11
2:    2      b      12
3:    3      a      13
4:    4      b      14

dt2 <- data.table(id_2 = 1:5,
                  name_2 = rep("a", 5),
                  score_2 = 21:25)
# dt2:
   id_2 name_2 score_2
1:    1      a      21
2:    2      a      22
3:    3      a      23
4:    4      a      24
5:    5      a      25
```

How can I combine `dt1` and `dt2` above using the two columns, `id_1` and `name_1` to get the following data table?

```
# desired data.table:
   id_1 name_1 score_1 score_2
1:    1      a      11      21
2:    2      b      12      NA
3:    3      a      13      23
4:    4      b      14      NA
```

I have tried the code below, but it does not produce the desired data.table above.

```
dt3 <- dt1[dt2, on = .(id_1 = id_2, name_1 = name_2)]
```

Also, can someone point me to a good vignette like the one below that covers the topic of joining / merging?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Comment: you should try `dt2[dt1,on = .(id_2 = id_1, name_2 = name_1)]` to get your output

Comment: This link might help you understand `join` in `data.table` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773822/why-does-xy-join-of-data-tables-not-allow-a-full-outer-join-or-a-left-join