# effectively add one data.table length according another table condition by matching corresponding column

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.table object:

```
dt <- data.table(
  a = c(1, 1, 2), 
  s = c(1, 2, 5), 
  o = c("A", "A", "A")
)

dt2 <- data.table(
  a = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  g = c(1, 2, 3, 4)  
)
```

There are two elements of **g** for each **a** in *dt2*. I want to match **a** in *dt* with the **a** in *dt2*. Then in *dt*, each row will duplicate 2 times (because there are 2 element for each **a** in *dt2*. Certainly, it may be different number of elements for each **a** in *dt2*. That means the condition in *dt2* determine how I append the corresponding **g** of *dt2* into *dt*), and append the corresponding **g** of *dt2* at the last column of *dt*. The final table should be like this:

```
fnl <- data.table(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
  s = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5), 
  o = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
  g = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4)
)
```

For clear, here is the two input tables and one output table.

```
> dt
   a s o
1: 1 1 A
2: 1 2 A
3: 2 5 A
> dt2
   a g
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
3: 2 3
4: 2 4
> fnl
   a s o g
1: 1 1 A 1
2: 1 1 A 2
3: 1 2 A 1
4: 1 2 A 2
5: 2 5 A 3
6: 2 5 A 4
```

I know that using for-loop I can do the task, but my data is too big, can you help figure out what is the effective way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using data.tables it's pretty easy:

```r
dt[dt2, on='a']
```

gives you

```
> dt[dt2, on='a']
   a s o g
1: 1 1 A 1
2: 1 2 A 1
3: 1 1 A 2
4: 1 2 A 2
5: 2 5 A 3
6: 2 5 A 4
```

Comment: Thank you. First time to know this powerful function.

Comment: Look here https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html and there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773822/why-does-xy-join-of-data-tables-not-allow-a-full-outer-join-or-a-left-join for more information. This JOINing function of data.tables is really awesome.